# Commandlog table record is missing the errormessage for errornumber 2508

Tags: ola-hallengren

We have deployed ola hallangren maintenance scripts in our environment. We noticed a record in commandlog table with text similar to 'DBCC CHECKDB (databasename) WITH all_errormsgs, no_infomsgs, data_purity executed by xxxxx found 7 errors and repaired 0 errors' , Error is 2508 but Errormessage is null.
We want to capture the errormessage for the errornumber 2508

Comment: This might be better suited as an issue for [Ola’s GitHub repo](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution).

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: SQL Version is 2019